Gatling Error Actor io.gatling.core.controller.Controller crashed on message Some(Start(io.gatling.core.scenario.Scenarios))
I am executing gatling script in my local system.
The same script works well in cloud, but failing in my local due to below error.:
i.g.c.c.Controller - Actor io.gatling.core.controller.Controller crashed on message Some(Start(io.gatling.core.scenario.Scenarios))
no request getting hit.
Requests

Global       (OK=0      KO=0     )

Th script works well in other people system also.
My java version is AppleJDK-11.0.20.8.2(tried with 17 also)
maven 3.9.6
scala maven plugin 4.5.6
